# Permalinks for CustomPostType with CustomTaxonomy in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

Using **CPT UI** I created a taxonomy "especialidades" and a post type "tab_especialidad" using my new taxonomy "especialidades".
I need the permalinks of the "tab_especialidad" post types like this:

http://webpage.com/especialidades/[taxonomy-slug(especialidades)]/[post-slug(tab_especialidad)]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/add-taxonomy-term-custom-post-permalinks-wordpress/

With just a small changes in my functions.php it's working :)